# Creating CNN model for multi-class image classification using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, multi-band, land-classification, deep-learning

I am trying to build a satellite image classifier CNN using Google Earth Engine.

I have been following this tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/UNET_regression_demo.ipynb#scrollTo=CTS7_ZzPDhhg

I am using 6 input bands (3RGB, 3IR) and 1 band for labels. By using neighbourhoodToArray() function, I construct a 256 x 256 rectangle so I can use it in a CNN classifier.

```
KERNEL_SIZE = 256
featureStack = ee.Image.cat([
  l8_image.select(BANDS),
  aafc_image.select(LABEL)
]).float()

list = ee.List.repeat(1, KERNEL_SIZE)
lists = ee.List.repeat(list, KERNEL_SIZE)
kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE, lists)
arrays = featureStack.neighborhoodToArray(kernel) 

n = 200 # Number of shards in the polygon.
N = 2000 # Total sample size in the polygon.

# Export all the training data (in many pieces), with one task 
# per geometry.
training = ee.FeatureCollection([])
for i in range(n):
    sample = arrays.sample(
      region = BOUNDED_AREA, 
      scale = 30,
      numPixels = N / n, # Size of the shard.
      seed = i, # random sample location seed
      tileScale = 8
    )
    training = training.merge(sample)
```

And then I export this to Drive and then get it back in a TFRecord format. But, when I get the data in a TFRecord format, the input is of shape (256, 256, 7) so I divide it into training and labels such that training is of shape (256, 256, 6) and labels is of shape (256, 256, 1).

But the thing here is that, I want my output node in the model to be a one-hot encoded vector that uses categorical cross entropy loss. But since my labels are in the shape of (256, 256, 1), I can't have it because the labels should have a form of (N_CLASSES,). To be more clear, my model should be in the form of:

```
model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256, 256,  6)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu), #4d
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu), # 4D
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu), # 4D
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), # 1D
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu), # 1D
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_CLASSES, activation=tf.nn.softmax) # (72,) 
])

# Compile the model with the specified loss function.
model2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history2 = model2.fit(x=training, epochs=5)
```

I have tried

```
def to_tuple(inputs):
  """Function to convert a dictionary of tensors to a tuple of (inputs, outputs).
  Turn the tensors returned by parse_tfrecord into a stack in HWC shape.
  Args:
    inputs: A dictionary of tensors, keyed by feature name.
  Returns:
    A tuple of (inputs, outputs).
  """
  inputsList = [inputs.get(key) for key in FEATURE_NAMES]
  stacked = tf.stack(inputsList, axis=0)
    # for Conv2D, input should be (BATCH, HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNEL)
    # Convert from CHW to HWC - meaning channel-height-width to height-width-channel
  stacked = tf.transpose(stacked, [1, 2, 0])
  labels = stacked[:, :, len(BANDS):] # first one is inputs (first 6 bands), second is only the last band - label
  reshaped_labels = tf.reshape(tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), [KERNEL_SIZE * KERNEL_SIZE])
  return stacked[:,:,:len(BANDS)], tf.one_hot(indices=reshaped_labels, depth=N_CLASSES) # depth makes the 2nd dimension 72
```

By doing so my labels is of shape (256*256, 72), but still not exactly what I want.

Is there a CNN classification tutorial I can follow (not UNET or regression)?

Comment: Hi, I have been struggling with the same issue. Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: @Learner Not really... I found out that I was trying to solve the wrong problem. I wanted to do a per-pixel classification and thought CNN was the way to go, but found that a better way to that is to use an FCNN so I switched my approach.